# PHP is there a built-in function to render ' as &rsquo; etc

Tags: php, chars

is there a built-in function to render characters like ' as identities (’) ?

also, is it unsafe to output raw characters (e.g ') in the html?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `htmlentities()`:

```
htmlentities("'", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true);
```

Regarding your second question, yes (as a general rule).

To output user input / raw input you should always use `htmlspecialchars()` at least.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities).  It will translate any character that has a HTML character entity equivalent.

It is not unsafe to output raw characters in your HTML, although there are a couple of caveats to that:

- It could produce invalid HTML if you are outputting them inside document entities or attributes.
- If it is user input, then it needs to be sanitized to prevent possible cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.